# What is the advantage of Sql Data Type numeric?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, numeric

What is the advantage of Sql numeric data type ( like numeric(10,2)). What is the difference between decimal and numeric? And also what is the type match in .net for numeric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK they are synomyms as far as TSQL is concerned. Re .NET; the only *direct* equivalent is [SqlNumeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal.aspx); `decimal` comes close, but doesn't have the same range etc.

Answer (score 3):

The numeric datatype is a fixed precision type. 
The advantage over float is that you know exactly how many decimal digits you have, with no approximation (with too big or too small numbers) so you can have correct significative figures.

[Decimal and Numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) are the same type in TSQL.

In .NET the matching type for numeric should be decimal

Answer (score 2):

According to the SQL standard (at least the [SQL-92 draft](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) that can be found on the web), the only difference is that `NUMERIC(N,M)` has *exactly* M total digits, while `DECIMAL(N,M)` is allowed to have *more* than M digits.

Answer (score 1):

from BOL

decimal and numeric:

**decimal**
   - Fixed precision and scale numeric data from -10^38 +1 through 10^38 –1.
**numeric**
   - Functionally equivalent to decimal.